# Why Pandas imports .csv as dataframe and Excel as dict?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, xlsx

I'm trying to import a CSV and Excel (xlsx) to process, merge, compute... however, when using pandas to import each, I get different data types:

```
import pandas as pd

ach_data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\temp\SHC v0.34.xlsm', sheet_name=['ABA_Accounts'])
c2c_import = pd.read_csv(r'C:\temp\C2C Import File.csv')

print('Excel: ' + str(type(ach_data)))
print('CSV: ' + str(type(c2c_import)))
```

Output:

```
Excel: <class 'dict'>
CSV: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Any reason why?

Comment: Please, read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) *"sheet_name: ... [0, 1, "Sheet5"]: Load first, second and sheet named “Sheet5” as a dict of DataFrame"* and *"Returns
DataFrame or dict of DataFrames
DataFrame from the passed in Excel file. See notes in sheet_name argument for more information on when a dict of DataFrames is returned."*

Answer (score 1):

It's because you pass a list to `sheet_name` parameter, use `sheet_name='ABA_Accounts'` instead:

```
ach_data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\temp\SHC v0.34.xlsm', sheet_name='ABA_Accounts')
```

If you read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) about what is returned:

> Returns DataFrame or **dict of DataFrames**
>
> DataFrame from the passed Excel file. See notes in **sheet_name** argument for more information on **when a dict of DataFrames is returned**.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a list as the `sheet_name` argument means that you want to read multiple sheets from the .xslm file as a dict of DataFrames.

An example from the docs:

> `[0, 1, "Sheet5"]`: Load first, second and sheet named "Sheet5" as a dict of DataFrame

If you only want one dataframe, just pass it as a string: `sheet_name='ABA_Accounts'`.